# Subject Tree in Dynamics Portal

Tags: dynamics-crm, liquid, adxstudio-portals, dynamics-crm-portals, powerapps-portal

I have a subject tree in the customer-service application. And we use that on the Create Case form on self-service portal.

We have a first field "Subject" and second one "Sub-subjects", on the portal they both display the same content.

The need is to select first the sub-subject, and should automatically get the parent (the subject)

Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

I followed this tuto: [Custom lookup filtering](https://www.dancingwithcrm.com/custom-lookup-filtering-powerapps-portal/)

To resume, I created a web template that will retrieve my Subjects, then I used the $getJSON to read the web template result.